# How to obtain the viewid in the tableau dashboard

Tags: tableau-api

background：
A tableau workbook with a dashboard containing some views. When downloading a PDF, I want to do the same as a public one by selecting specific views in this dashboard for download. I hope to obtain all the viewids in this dashboard. I cannot directly use the showExportPDFDialog method because I need to add watermarks to the downloaded PDF.

problem：A tableau dashboard that contains some views, and I hope to obtain all the viewids in this dashboard

I hope to obtain all the viewids in this dashboard
[image: The picture is the effect I want]

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to download a PDF, you can just add .pdf to the end of the URL.

https://mytableauserver/views/myview.pdf